# Docker couchbase and Nodejs connection refuse (1024) - docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, couchbase

Hi guys I've been debugging since yesterday I have nodejs app and couchbase images,
the problem is my nodejs can't connect with my couchbase please see error below. every time I press the login button this error appears

```
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: LCB_ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (1024): The 
remote host refused the connection
```

here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
   container_name: web
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - db
    links: 
      - "db:database"
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: couchbase
    ports:
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11210:11210
```

here's my Dockerfile in my node app

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
CMD ["node","index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

and finally here's my connection string to couchbase index.js

```
const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster("couchbase://db:8091/",
    username: 'Administrator',
    password: 'password'
})
```

Comment: This might not be the issue, but if you use `couchbase://` connection strings, I don't think you need to use the port number

Comment: Also, you're just using the base couchbase image in your YAML file... at what point do you actually set it up, create a cluster, and create the Administrator/password credentials? Is that something you're doing manually?

Comment: If this is for testing, [Testcontainers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcontainers) is a useful tool for running temporary containers. There's an unofficial [testcontainers-couchbase module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kralphs/testcontainers-couchbase)  that takes care of all of the cluster setup tasks Matt Groves was referring to.